# Codeigniter - Message: Undefined variable: site_name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have no problem in displaying all the players in the database,
my problem is I want to display all the players dependent on the location(site)

Player's table = player_fname,player_lname,site_name.

model:

```
public function sitePlayers($site_name){


     $sql = "SELECT * FROM players where site_name =  ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($site_name)) ; 
    }
```

controller

```
public function editview($session_id)
    {


        $this->load->model('Session_model');

        $sessionplayers = $this->Session_model->sitePlayers($site_name);            
        $this->load->view('sessionf/Session_manage',['sessionplayers'=>$sessionplayers]);       
    }
```

Comment: Check your controller, maybe you need to set `$site_name`  first

Comment: Message: Missing argument 2 for Sessions::editview(), got error mate... 
public function editview($session_id,$site_name)

Comment: echo $this-db->last_query();exit;
And run that query what it displays in phpmyadmin.

Comment: i dont understand :/ newbie here sorry

Comment: Tip: How to pass data to view in codeigniter https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller: You did not  define $site_name; thats why it threw an error $site_name not found;

```
public function editview($session_id)
{


    $this->load->model('Session_model');
    // define $site_name;
    $sessionplayers = $this->Session_model->sitePlayers($site_name);            
    $this->load->view('sessionf/Session_manage',['sessionplayers'=>$sessionplayers]);       
}
```

define $site_name and its good.